# Cucumber after each test I need to run a specific scenario, same as Background. Background is for before each, do we have similar for after each

Tags: automation, background, cucumber, cypress

Groups page functionality

Background:
Given When the user logs in
Then add the test group

@smoke
Scenario: Verify the groups list page
When the user opens the groups page
Then the group's page title should be visible

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber does not have an after hook like background, but there is a workaround: if you want to run a after hook for a specific feature file then add a tag to the feature file, and then use that tag to write an after hook in the env file.

The given example is for capyabra with ruby

Test.feature

```
@test_tag
Feature: test feature file
```

env.rb file

```rb
After('@test_tag') do
  # code for after hook
end
```

If you want to run an after hook for a specific scenario, use the same method. Add a tag for the scenario and pass it in after hook.

```
After('scenario1') do
  # code
end
```

If you want a general after hook to run after every scenario, then we can directly write the `After` hook without tag

Example:

```rb
After do
  # code
end
```

**Note:** The scenario parameter passed gives information for the scenario e.g `scenario.failed?` to check if the scenario ran successfully if you want to run logic not associated with scenario details in the `After hook` you can omit the parameter

Example:

```rb
After do|scenario|
  if scenario.failed?
    page.save_screenshot("path_#{scenario.name.parameterize}.png")
  end
end
```